# Raspberry Pi 3 model B doesn't work on laptop screen

Tags: raspbian, pi-3

I have bought a Raspberry Pi 3 model B (UK) and wanted to start working with it. Following the online tutorials,

- I downloaded Raspbian from [here](https://downloads.raspberrypi.org/raspbian_latest) and used Etcher to write the ISO file on my SD card.
- Then I inserted the SD card into my RPi and plugged in the LAN & HDMI cable into my laptop and RPi.
- Then I plugged in the power cable from my 2.1A android charger but nothing happened on my laptop. Only the red LED and a blinking green LED and 2 Ethernet LEDs turned on on the board.

I compared the SHA-256 hash from my ISO file and the one on the website and **they were not the same**.

Is that the reason why my RPi didn't work? What should I do now ?

Comment: Try reflasing the SD card and perhaps change the card to another one.

Comment: A laptop is not a monitor. Plug the hdmi into a monitor or display that supports hdmi.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I got the answer of your question, that if you has been abled to connect raspberry pi to laptop then, simply go to network settings in **Control panel** Open change adapter options 
Here you'll have to shared your

> Wifi Network 
>   To
>
> Ethernet 
>   One more things that you need to keep in mind that your laptop must be connected through a network via wifi, you may use your mobile hot-spot... 
>   Then plugin your Ethernet cable into laptop, then start
>
> XMING server in your laptop simply download from internet.
>   And putty also... 
>   Then start these both applications together 
>   First xming then putty.... 
>   Putty Configuration : In the session tab type Host Name : raspberrypi.mshome.net on port 22 which is default.
>   select : SSH connection type.
>   Save it and load. 
>   Then move on the SSH tab on   side in putty application.
>   And expend it and then

Select X11.
Enable X11forwarding by putting 
"localhost:0"
 in X display location.
Finally communication settings done. 
Now open putty and load those session that was saved by you.
You'll notice a black display will appear which ask about login, it's ok credentials are given here login : pi
Password : raspberrypi 
Done type commands to start gui 
lxterminal
a terminal will appear in that type
"startx" for linux
And "lxde" for Ubuntu 
If it doesn't work,  don't worry about this
You can start gui manually 
By simply type "pcmanfm" that will open file explorer in that go to application tab where you'll find the python and other applications that compatible to raspberrypi.

Answer (score 7):

If I understood your situation correctly, you plugged the HDMI cable from the RPi into your laptop. You should plug the HDMI cable from the RPi into a TV or LCD Monitor that has HDMI input. Then you should see the system starting on the monitor.

Red LED and blinking Green LED usually means the system is working.

Also for debugging purposes you can use a USB-serial adapter and check the booting messages with picocom, minicom, putty or any other serial program.

Answer (score 1):

I use HDMI as my primary PI video output. As others have said, the HDMI port on your laptop is also only an OUTPUT port.  I use DVI to HDMI adapter to access old monitors, I also use VGA to HDMI adapters, again for older monitors. Most LCD monitors less than 10 years old have these two types of input.

The adapter dongles are available at most online retailers, at a reasonable price, for a "dongle".  There may also be USB 2.0 to HDMI adapters? You would have to make sure no driver is needed, or a driver for Debian 9 for ARMhr processors.

Your Raspberry Pi from your description is working. You just need a proper video display device.  You could use any 1080p TV.  Just select the correct HDMI channel.  Good luck

Comment: Yes, there is the "remote connection" option from a remote device to a "server device".  The remote device could be a laptop, desktop, or another Raspberry Pi, or any other *nix device. Windown & MacOS sould work too.  You need a server service, and a client tool to do the connection.  SSH (secure socket shell) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Shell which is a "terminal" only connection. Putty is one SSH client.  VNC is another protocol.  It is a GUI client/server set of tools. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_Network_Computing  Both protocols are opensourse.